# Tree generation using L-systems and Python turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, l-systems

I'm trying to generate a simple tree using an L-system. However, when I run the code that I have:

```
import turtle


def generate(length):
    sentence = "F"
    for j in range(1, length):
        for i in sentence:
            if i == "F":
                sentence += "FF+[+F-F-F]-[-F+F+F]"

        print(sentence)


    gen = turtle.Turtle()
    window = turtle.Screen()
    gen.left(90)

    for k in sentence:
        if k == "F":
            gen.forward(10)
        elif k == "+":
            gen.right(10)
        elif k == "-":
            gen.left(10)
        elif k == "[":
            location = gen.position()
        elif k == "]":
            gen.setposition(location)
```

I get a weird grain pattern in the turtle window:

[image: turtle window]

How can I produce the desired result?

Comment: >>> generate(3), 3 being the length of the string aka complexity of the tree

Comment: OK, when I run that I don't get your visual. I get "F" spammed on the console and the window closes immediately. Can you post the exact code you're using to generate the image you posted? I can say for sure that `sentence.replace` does not do what you think it does--it replaces _every occurrence_ of the first parameter with the second and it doesn't do it in place. Beyond that, I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I made a small mistake in the if i == "F" statement, replace
sentence.replace(i, "FF+[+F-F-F]-[-F+F+F]") with sentence += "FF+[+F-F-F]-[-F+F+F]"

Comment: I don't think that's what you want either. Please edit your post to provide these updates.

Comment: Ok, I edited it, How would I improve my code to get the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `+=` operation appends the application of the production rule to the string but the idea is to *replace* each occurrence of the `"F"` character with the result of the production rule.

You can do this with [`string#replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace), which replaces every occurrence of a substring. You used this before your edit, but didn't assign the return value of the function back to the original `sentence` variable (`replace` doesn't work [in-place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm) and strings are immutable).

Either way, the extra inner loop is unnecessary.

Another important point: the production rule is recursive, so a single `location` variable is insufficient storage to "remember" the sequence of pushes that might have been performed.

To elaborate, here's an excerpt of your `sentence` variable after applying the production rule on multiple iterations:

```
...[-FF+[+F-F-F]-[-F+F+F]+...
```

It's clear that this has two sequential `[` operations before a `]` is encountered. This nesting can grow arbitrarily deep. A [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)) data structure is the best way to keep track of the nested, recursive positions (`location` can only keep track of the last and state would be corrupted when two push operations occur in succession).

Whenever a `[` operation is encountered, push the position on the stack (represented in Python as a list which only uses `append` (for push) and `pop` without any arguments to remove the back of the list). Whenever a `]` operation is encountered, pop the stack and set the turtle's position to that location.

As a minor point, it's a good idea to keep hardcoded values out of the code; group all of your settings/config vars at the top of the block. If you are using a function, make these parameters.

Here's a working version:

```
import turtle

generations = 3
size = 10
rule = ("F", "FF+[+F-F-F]-[-F+F+F]")
sentence = "F"
positions = []
gen = turtle.Turtle()
gen.speed(10)
gen.left(90)

for i in range(generations):
    sentence = sentence.replace(*rule)

for op in sentence:
    if op == "F":
        gen.forward(size)
    elif op == "+":
        gen.right(size)
    elif op == "-":
        gen.left(size)
    elif op == "[":
        positions.append(gen.position())
    elif op == "]":
        gen.setposition(positions.pop())

turtle.exitonclick()
```